# Clicking on the link in android webview does not get highlighted visually

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have an android application that launches the webview. When any link is clicked on the webview I don't get any visual 
feedback that the link is clicked. So, user does not know if the link is clicked untill the page is loaded.

Is there any way to in which we can make webview give the highlight the moment any link is clicked on the webview? So that the user will know that the link is clicked. Kindly update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem .What i found the problem was with the setJavascriptEnabled(true) flag.Set this flag according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this feedback in your html/css file:

```
.button:active
{
  background-color: gray;
}
```